Google Earth doesn't accept WMS Cadastrial Layers (ITALY)
I have a similar problem when try to push Google Earth to accept a WMS layer. This is the official Cadastral WMS for Italy and the address I give to QGIS is simply
https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?
this is the "GetCapabilitiesUrl"
Any suggestion ?

Maybe this can help: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

The issue is that service doesn't support EPSG:4326 (WMS 1.1.1) or CRS:84 (WMS 1.3.0).  Google Earth requires this CRS to be able to work.
See Google Earth WMS fails for a fuller explanation

You might try with epsg:4258 and WMS version 1.1.1 with a connection string like: https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php?service=WMS&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&version=1.1.1&request=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&FORMAT=image/png&SRS=EPSG:4258&STYLES=&LAYERS={layer of interest}&  Note too that the service layers are scale layered, so you may need to zoom in to get any map
